Did Concordes have de-icing boots?
Concordes were a supersonic passenger aircraft of which only 20 were built from 1965 to 1979 and were retired in 2003 for expense reasons and non-fuel efficiency. The plane was placed into regular service in 1976.
Did this aircraft have de-icing boots?

This question is similar to: Ice Protection System for supersonic aircraft. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, the Concorde had heated strips (not boots) on the leading edge, they are labelled 92 and 93 in the following cutaway (source):

